# Advice about why my answer deleted?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/275074/133290

After it was deleted, I've edited it to include a summary.

I'm not sure if my answer wasn't clear before or it was perceived as technically lacking.

I thought my answer was well implied by the details in the answer, but the summary should make my thoughts clear.

Can it be undeleted and just left to the whim of the voters at least? I think artistic perspective is useful to that question (as long as it's not wrong about the technology).

Answer (score 3):

Your answer is just another version of "that's all the gain you should need" (similar to several already existing answers), which really doesn't address the *technical* reasons the gain might need to be limited, which have to do with the limited gain-bandwidth product of the device and its finite open-loop gain.

However, it's all a very gray area, so I will restore your answer.